# Chrome Extension Corrupted and Changed by Malware

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got a fairly popular chrome extension, over time I've got sporadic reports from users that this extension is malware, which of course it is not.
I've recently learned that there are malware programs who change the files of the chrome extension and make turn it into a malware.
Is there any way I can defend my extension from this kind of changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to!

Chrome has a built-in mechanism preventing it. Any extension installed from Web Store will have a signed hash of all files included.

At any time when Chrome loads an extension, those hashes are checked, and if any file is modified Chrome marks the extension as potentially compromised, disables it and warns the user of unauthorized changes.

---

That said, this only protects static files you have in your extension.

If you rely on external scripts, it's your duty to protect them from man-in-the-middle attacks. Chrome's [default extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) does a good job of securing against the worst offenders, but still - if you use dynamic code, it's your responsibility to secure it, especially if you override the CSP.

Finally, if you're using a Native Host module, it's not secured. Treat it as untrusted.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I actually know that, but there's a few caveats with that:
1. It doesn't happen immediately
2. I'm losing users this way as the extension is disabled and then users either ignore it, uninstall the extension or think the extension did it.

So - there's no way to protect against it?
There's no plans by Google to auto fix issues like that by restoring the code or preventing the files from being modified?